# Mouseover event filter for a PyQT Label

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseover

I've been trying to convert the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562447/pyqt-how-to-catch-mouse-over-event-of-qtablewidget-headers) to work with a simple label.

Here's the code:

```
class mouseoverEvent(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(mouseoverEvent, self).__init__(parent)
    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            print "mousemove!"
            
self.filter = mouseoverEvent(self)
self.label.installEventFilter(self.filter)
```

Now curiously, this actually works, but not without my console being spammed with "mousemove!" (good) as well as the error: **TypeError: invalid result type from mouseoverEvent.eventFilter()**

I've not quite figured out the complex relationship between events yet, so this is a bit greek to me. So, what gives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my case I had to set label attribute of `QLabel` to `Qt.WA_Hover` and catch/handle the `QHoverEvent` even of the `QLabel`. Might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you need to return `True` or `False` from the eventFilter, to indicate whether you have handled the event completely or not.

Comment: Yep. I just tested it. Works like a charm. Thanks, @jkerian.

Answer (score 0):

Check out what I just discovered. This is a snippet from some actual code, so class names are specific in my instance.

```
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event=None):
        if self.activeLayer.layerName != 'Whiteboard': super(MapPage, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        else:
            if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribbling:
                self.drawLineTo(event.scenePos())
```

What I have done is re-declared the mouseMoveEvent, but if the running instance of the activeLayer is not named 'Whiteboard' then the software runs through an 'original' mouseMoveEvent.

Answer (score 0):

class mouseoverEvent(QtCore.QObject):
    def **init**(self, parent):
        super(mouseoverEvent, self).**init**(parent)

```
def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
        print "mousemove!"
    return super(mouseoverEvent, self).eventFilter(object, event)
```

self.filter = mouseoverEvent(self)
self.label.installEventFilter(self.filter)